# with azure free trial account, can i deploy a bot to MS teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have developed a bot by modifying the template provided from https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk. The bot works perfectly in the Bot Framework Emulator.

I have tried to deploy it by using my trial account. it looks like it is lack of some accesses, which i am not quite sure.

my question is, if i plan to deploy this bot into MS teams installed on my computer, can it be fulfilled by using my trial account in Azure? or i need to purchase a paid account?

Regards,

Comment: Could you post/describe the error/issue you are actually seeing when trying to deploy your bot

Comment: Hi Mars, thanks for replying. i have started deployment yet. just generically ask whether it is feasible or not? if it is possible, i will go ahead; if not, i will apply a paid account.

Comment: Yes, You can create trial account and deploy a bot in MS Teams. [Create Azure free account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/search/?&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIq_Htwue55wIVjTgrCh14XgShEAAYASAAEgL7ufD_BwE:G:s&OCID=AID2000081_SEM_MQp5XYKR&MarinID=MQp5XYKR_324551657415_microsoft%20azure%20trial%20account_e_c__66077224680_kwd-313489406130&lnkd=Google_Azure_Brand&dclid=CKrimIjwuecCFQkJtwAd3toBFg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely possible to run in on Azure, and everything will work 100% fine a free trial account, or of course with a paid account. Be aware that the "web app bot" template will default to a "standard" pricing model in Azure, which will use $70 of your credit, so you should change it to a cheaper price plan immediately, especially if you're just using this for development. There's even a "Free" option (i.e. free forever, even after the Free  Trial expires), but then it's limited to how many hours per day the bot will run.

Another option is to host your bot in an Azure Function ("serverless"), but it's a lot more work as the samples and wizards on the internet mostly use the Azure Web App model, so you'd need to manually convert it over to running that way. Certainly you can get started with the free trial though!

As another completely possible option, if this is just for development, then you can run the bot on your local machine, using Ngrok, which creates an real, live "https" address for you, that Teams can accept to work with your bot,  even though it's running from your local machine. This is of course great for development/debugging, but not realistic for a live deployment.